# 3D Texture Rendering Using 2D Texture

Tags: opengl-es, texture-mapping, glsles

I want render 3d texture at OpenGL es 2.0 environment. So I make 3d texture data to 2d texture.

```
3d texture (256 * 256 * 100) -> 2d texture(2560 * 2560)
```

I think two offsets are same.

```
offset = z3 * 256 * 256 + y3 * 256 + x3      
offset = y2 * 2560 + x2
```

But result is not good.

```c
vec3 size3 = vec3(256.0, 256.0, 100.0);
vec2 size2 = vec2(2560.0, 2560.0);

vec2 calc3dTo2d(vec3 coords) {
    vec3 offset3 = vec3(coords.x * size3.x, coords.y * size3.y, coords.z * size3.z);

    float offset = offset3.z * size3.x * size3.y + offset3.y * size3.x + offset3.x;

    float y = floor(offset / size2.x) / size2.y;
    float x = fract(offset / size2.x);

    return vec2(x, y);
}
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: What precision are you using? You're going to need highp for something like this. Note that GLES2 allows implementation to not support highp in fragment shaders (but that would likely only affect older devices).

Comment: IPad mini5 is used. I'm using gl es2 , glsl es 1.0 and ios GLKit. so... is it impossible to implement 3d texture with gl es2?

Comment: I know the problem. Texture interpolation caculation is not good for this situation. After floor calculation to the values of offset3, it work properly